# Create single VSTO addin for All Ms Office components and its deployment

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-office, vsto

I want to create a single VSTO addin for all MS office components.
So far I have get individual addins for each component like Word Addin,Excel Addin etc..
But I want to create a single addin for all Ms Office components and also in single deployment it will be added in all ms office components.
I have to add a custom task pane  and a ribbon tab in each ms office component,so rather than duplicating the task in each individual addin project,I want a single addin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSTO doesn't support creating multi-host add-ins. You need to develop a separate add-in for each Office application. An alternative way is to develop a shared add-in.

You may also consider using [Add-in Express](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/index.php) instead. It allows to to create one Visual Studio project that supports all versions (2000, XP, 2003, 2007, 2010 and 2013) and editions (Student, Home, Professional etc.) of Microsoft Office and target multiple applications in the Microsoft Office suite (Outlook, Word, Excel, PowerPoint and other apps.)

Comment: Can I create a single deployment set then?

Comment: Yes, you can even include several VSTO add-ins into a single installaltion package. See [Deploying an Office Solution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.aspx).